# set permissions with a vbs script

Tags: vbscript

I have a VBS script that downloads a file on login and places it in a given folder, It works brilliantly in some places but in others it falls over because the file was created by user1 and user2 can't overwrite it.

How would i give the group "Everyone" full control of a given file using a VBS script?

Answer (score 4):

Something like this:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strFile = "c:\test_folder\test_file.txt"
setPerms = "%COMSPEC% /c echo Y| C:\windows\system32\cacls.exe " & Chr(34) & strFile & Chr(34) & " /G domain\everyone:F"

wscript.echo setPerms
WshShell.run setPerms
```

Partially gleaned from here:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/ITCG/thread/6CDA091A-6B3D-4F58-8374-9A46F59F389A

Answer (score 3):

One way of doing it would be to use the [CACLS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490872.aspx) command line tool. Just run it from your script using [Shell.Run](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Here's another [link](http://ss64.com/nt/cacls.html) to information about how to use CACLS that has some samples.

Answer (score 0):

Function giveFullPermissionToFolder(strFolder)

Dim objShell, strCmd, intRunError

Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

strCmd = "%comspec% /c echo Y| cacls " & strFolder & " /T /E /C /G Users:F"

intRunError = objShell.Run(strCmd, 2, True)

If intRunError<>0 Then

```
Reporter.ReportEvent micFail, "giveFullPermissionToFolder" , "Unable to give full permission to " & strFolder
```

End If

Set objShell=Nothing

End Function